# Interactive Xarray dataset raster visualisation app using Panel and hvplot

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot, panel-pyviz

I am trying to replicate the [Glaciers Demo](https://glaciers.pyviz.demo.anaconda.com/glaciers) using an Xarray of geospatial data. I am able to create pretty much exactly what I want but I am trying to create a Panel app that allows the user to select the `data_vars`, each of which has different dimensions that I want make interactable, and visualize on an interactive map with at least the continents contour. Here is what my Xarray Dataset looks like :
[image]

```py
def plot(field):
    return xds[field].hvplot.image().opts(cmap='jet',height=650,width=1300,data_aspect=1)
interact(plot, field = list(xds.data_vars))
```

and here is what the code above produces in a notebook :
[image]

I would like to integrate the selector for the `data_vars` and then depending on its dimensions have interactive maps with controls for all its dimensions (ES has (time, pres1, lat, lon) while P0 has only (time, lat, lon)) and I would like to have the controls in the `sidebar` and the plots in the `main` of the following template :

```py
from turtle import width
from matplotlib.pyplot import title
import panel as pn
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from panel.template import DefaultTheme
from pathlib import Path
import fstd2nc
import hvplot.xarray
import xarray as xr
from unicodedata import name
import hvplot
import param
from panel.interact import interact

pn.extension(sizing_mode='stretch_width')

bootstrap = pn.template.MaterialTemplate(title='Material Template', theme=DefaultTheme, )

glob_path = Path(r"C:\Users\spart\Documents\Anaconda-Work-Dir")
file_list = [str(pp).split('\\')[-1] for pp in glob_path.glob("2022*")]

phase = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name="Phase", start=0, end=np.pi)
fileSel = pn.widgets.Select(name='Select File', options=file_list)

@pn.depends(fileSel=fileSel)
def selectedFile(fileSel):
    base_path = r"C:\Users\spart\Documents\Anaconda-Work-Dir\{}".format(fileSel)
    return pn.widgets.StaticText(name='Selected', value=base_path)

@pn.depends(fileSel=fileSel)
def dataXArray(fileSel):
    base_path = r"C:\Users\spart\Documents\Anaconda-Work-Dir\{}".format(fileSel)
    xds = fstd2nc.Buffer(base_path).to_xarray()
    return xds.ES.hvplot( width=500)

bootstrap.sidebar.append(fileSel)
bootstrap.sidebar.append(selectedFile)

bootstrap.main.append(
    pn.Row(
        pn.Card(hv.DynamicMap(dataXArray), title='Plot'),
    )
)

bootstrap.show()
```

EDIT :  Here is a [link to an example dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1huivRiCfo7qU6I9zq6AzoueL3VmFiE-g/view?usp=sharing) which can be loaded with the following code

```py
xds = fstd2nc.Buffer(PATH_TO_FILE).to_xarray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the data file I can't easily run the code, but some observations:

- If using bare functions like this rather than classes, I'd recommend using `pn.bind` rather than `pn.depends`; it really helps get the code organized better.
- For a simple application like this, I'd use hvPlot .interactive: https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Interactive.html
- I can't seem to find this in the docs, but you can pull out the widgets from the result of dataXArray (or any other hvplot or holoviews object) using `.widgets()`, and you can then put that in the sidebar. You can then pull out just the plot using `.panel()`, and put that in the main area.

If that helps you get it done, then great; if not please post a sample data file or two so that it's runnable, and I can look into it further. And please submit a PR to the docs once you get it working so that future users have less trouble!

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments sir. I will keep trying to get it working as I am learning, but in the meantime I have shared a link to an example file which I use to develop and which you can run my script with to get something similar to me and help understand the best practices for `quadmesh` and `.image` as well as the coastline and rasterize options.